# Script para adicionar músicas

Tags: javascript, html5, áudio

Olá, tenho um `script` que toca as músicas automaticamente usando a tag `<audio>` do `html5`, o problema é que quero puxar todas as músicas de dentro da pasta que coloquei as músicas sem ter que adicionar manualmente, alguém teria um simples exemplo de como fazer isso?

Segue o print do que já tem feito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu arquivo `.js`:

```
audioPlayer();

function audioPlayer() {

    var currentSong = 0;

    $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];

    $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
    $("#playlist li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
        $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");

        currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
    });

    $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function () {
        currentSong++;
        if (currentSong == $("playlist li a").length) {
            currentSong = 0;
        }

        $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
        $("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
    });
}
```

Meu arquivo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Audio Player</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <audio src="" controls id="audioPlayer">
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5!
    </audio>

    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="current-song">
            <a href="assets/songs/Bruninho & Davi - E Essa Boca Aí- ft. Luan Santana.mp3">Bruninho & Davi - E Essa Boca Aí- ft. Luan Santana</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="assets/songs/COLO - Jads Jadson part Victor Leo.mp3">COLO - Jads Jadson part Victor Leo</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="assets/songs/Felipe e Ferrari part Bruno e Marrone Tira a mao de mim.mp3">Felipe e Ferrari part Bruno e Marrone Tira a mao de mim</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="assets/songs/Fernando e Sorocaba - Paga pau.mp3">Fernando e Sorocaba - Paga pau</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="assets/songs/Junior e Thyago - Os cachorros de goias.mp3">Junior e Thyago - Os cachorros de goias</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```